# JOINTJS: Get children recursively of a parent

Tags: parent-child, hierarchy, jointjs

How can i get all children recursively in jointjs.

I have done embedding in correct order.

I have done some homework in trying to find the answer, I have been using `cell.getNeighbours()`.

But this does not help me in retrieving what i want.It only give the first child or first neighbours.

Since the embedding is done correct, I was thinking to use `cell.getEmbeddedCells()`.

I am looking for help in creating a recursive function using `cell.getEmbeddedCells()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNeightbors()` is for retrieving neighbors of an element in terms of links (both inbound and outbound) that are connected to that element. This has nothing to do with embeds. For retrieving all the embedded cells and their embedded cells recursively, you can do something like this:

```
var subtree = [];
function collectDeepEmbedded(cell) {
   _.each(cell.getEmbeddedCells(), function(c) {
      subtree.push(c);
      collectDeepEmbedded(c);
   })   
}
collectDeepEmbedded(myCell);
```

Comment: Its perfect... Your answer is the one i was looking for,...worked like a charm.Thanks a lot.